# What does `int j = i + rand()/(RAND_MAX /(curr_pos-i) + 1);` mean?

Tags: c

What does the following code mean? What is RAND_MAX? I find this code very hard to understand for some reason. The part I don't understand is `int j = i + rand()/(RAND_MAX /(curr_pos-i) + 1);`.

```
if (curr_pos > 1) {
  for (int i = 0; i < curr_pos-1; i++) {
    int j = i + rand()/(RAND_MAX /(curr_pos-i) + 1);
    swap(&array[j], &array[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a Fisher-Yates shuffle. The initial `if` statement is not needed since the loop condition already handles that case. The line in the title is generating a random number in the [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) `[i, curr_pos)`.

Comment: @user3386109 Well, given the little code posted, we don't know if `curr_pos` has a signed or *unsigned* type.

Comment: @Bob__ If `curr_pos` is unsigned, then the code has a signed/unsigned comparison that needs to be fixed. So yes, I did assume that the code compiles without warnings. Code with warnings is garbage that isn't worth discussing. To be clear, if `curr_pos` is unsigned then the correct way to write the loop is `for (size_t i=0; i+1 < curr_pos; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RAND_MAX`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/) is a macro, defined in `stdlib.h`:

> Maximum value returned by rand

We divide `rand()` by `RAND_MAX` in order to get **Integer Division**.

So here we have:

```
int j = i + rand()/(RAND_MAX /(curr_pos-i) + 1);
```

which says, assign to `j` the value of `i`, plus:

```
rand()/(RAND_MAX /(curr_pos-i) + 1)
```

which means: divide `rand()` by:

```
RAND_MAX /(curr_pos-i) + 1
```

Here, `curr_pos-i` will be evaluated first, and then we will divide `RAND_MAX` by its the subtraction's result. Then we will add `1` to the result of the devision.

---

PS: This code looks like it tries to implement [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), although the if statement is unnecessary, as @user3386109 commented.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `rand` ranges from zero to `RAND_MAX`. So dividing it by `RAND_MAX+1`, using real-number arithmtic, yields a value in [0, 1). (That is the interval of numbers from 0 to 1, including 0 and excluding 1.) If we multiply that by *x*, it will be a value in [0, *x*).

Thus, using real-number arithmetic, `rand() / (RAND_MAX+1) * (curr_pos-i)` would give a number in [0, `curr_pos-i`). That expression is equivalent to `rand() / ((RAND_MAX+1)/(curr_pos-i))`, and that is very similar to the expression in the code, `rand() / (RAND_MAX/(curr_pos-i) + 1)`. So we have a clue about what it is intended to do: It may be attempting to generate a random number in [0, `curr_pos-i`).

The differences are due to using integer arithmetic instead of real-number arithmetic. If we used the code `rand() / ((RAND_MAX+1)/(curr_pos-i))`, the division by `curr_pos-i` would round down, and that could make the final result larger than we want; it could include `curr_pos-i` instead of excluding it.

Instead, the code uses `RAND_MAX/(curr_pos-i) + 1` as the quotient. Note that if the division in `RAND_MAX/(curr_pos-i)` rounds down, it discards some fraction less than 1. So adding 1 means the result is necessarily larger than the real-number quotient `RAND_MAX/(curr_pos-i)`. And therefore `rand() / ((RAND_MAX+1)/(curr_pos-i))` cannot equal `curr_pos-i`; it must be less than it.

Now we know `rand() / ((RAND_MAX+1)/(curr_pos-i))` generates a number in [0, `curr_pos-i`). Then adding `i` to this generates a number in [`i`, `curr_pos`).

Since that sum is assigned to `j`, `swap(&array[j], &array[i]);` swaps `array[i]` with some other array element from `i` (inclusive) to `curr_pos` (exclusive).

Since this is done in a loop, `for (int i = 0; i < curr_pos-1; i++)`, each element in array before `curr_pos` is swapped with a “random” element (possibly itself). The result is to shuffle all elements in `array` before `curr_pos`.

(One thing to note is that due to the truncations in integer arithmetic and the fact that `RAND_MAX` will have a limited number of factors, the distribution of “random” numbers selected will have some irregularities. The shuffles obtained may not be uniformly distributed over all possible shuffles.)